# When I am trying to call a specific number from listview, the dialer shows me some wierd number

Tags: java, android

When I am trying to call a number from listview, the dialer opens but shows me some different. The listview consists of two image button, one button is used to make call.

This is my Custom Adapater Class   EmergencyNumCustomAdapaterForCall.java.

```
package com.example.panicapp;

import java.util.List;

import com.example.panicapp.AppDao.AddEmerNumAuthenticationDao;
import com.example.panicapp.AppModel.AddEmergencyNumber;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;



public class EmergencyNumCustomAdapaterForCall extends ArrayAdapter<AddEmergencyNumber> implements ListAdapter{

    private List<AddEmergencyNumber> lsadd;
    private LayoutInflater inflator;
    private AddEmerNumAuthenticationDao emerdao=null;

    public EmergencyNumCustomAdapaterForCall(AddEmergencyNumberForCall addnum, List<AddEmergencyNumber> ls) 
    {
        super(addnum, R.layout.activity_custom_numberlisting, ls);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.lsadd=ls;
        inflator=addnum.getLayoutInflater();

    }


    static class ViewHolder
    {
        protected TextView emernumber;
        protected ImageButton imgbtncall;
        protected ImageButton imgbtnDelete;

    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder viewholder=null;
        final int temposition=arg0;
        if(arg1==null)
        {
            arg1=inflator.inflate(R.layout.activity_custom_numberlisting, null);
            viewholder=new ViewHolder();
            viewholder.emernumber=(TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.txt_numberlisting);
            viewholder.imgbtncall=(ImageButton)arg1.findViewById(R.id.img_numberlisting);
            viewholder.imgbtnDelete=(ImageButton)arg1.findViewById(R.id.img_numdelete);
            viewholder.imgbtnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    emerdao=new AddEmerNumAuthenticationDao(getContext());
                    emerdao.deleteCallNum(lsadd.get(temposition).getEmergencyNumber());
                    Log.i("Authentication", "Number Deleted");
                }
            });

            viewholder.imgbtncall.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    emerdao=new AddEmerNumAuthenticationDao(getContext());
                    emerdao.getEmergencyNumberForCalling(lsadd.get(temposition).getEmergencyNumber());
                    String number=""+emerdao;
                    System.out.println(number);
                    Log.i("Number", "Calling Number");
                    Intent callintent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" +emerdao));
                    getContext().startActivity(callintent); 
                }
            });



            arg1.setTag(viewholder);
            arg1.setTag(R.id.txt_numberlisting, viewholder.emernumber);
            arg1.setTag(R.id.img_numberlisting, viewholder.imgbtncall);
            arg1.setTag(R.id.img_numdelete, viewholder.imgbtnDelete);
        }
        else
        {
            viewholder=(ViewHolder)arg1.getTag();
        }
        viewholder.imgbtncall.setTag(arg0);
        viewholder.imgbtnDelete.setTag(arg0);
        viewholder.emernumber.setText(lsadd.get(arg0).getEmergencyNumber());
        return arg1;
        }





}
```

This is my database class

```
package com.example.panicapp.AppDao;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.example.panicapp.AppModel.AddEmergencyNumber;
import com.example.panicapp.AppUtill.DbUtill;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class AddEmerNumAuthenticationDao extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements AddEmerNumAuthenticationListener{

    private SQLiteDatabase sqlDb=null;

    public AddEmerNumAuthenticationDao(Context context) {
        super(context, DbUtill.DATABASE_NAME, null, DbUtill.DATABASE_VERSION);
        Log.i("AuthenticationDao", "This is AuthenticationDao constructor.....");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public List<AddEmergencyNumber> getAllEmergencyNumberforcall() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<AddEmergencyNumber> addemergnum=new ArrayList<AddEmergencyNumber>();
        sqlDb=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor=null;
        cursor=sqlDb.query(DbUtill.TABLE_ADD_EMERGENCY_NUMBER, new String[] {DbUtill.EMERGENCYNUMBER,DbUtill.CALL}, DbUtill.CALL+"=?", new String[] {"1"}, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while(!cursor.isAfterLast())
        {
            AddEmergencyNumber addnum=new AddEmergencyNumber();
            addnum.setEmergencyNumber(cursor.getString(0));
            addnum.setCall(cursor.getInt(1));
            addemergnum.add(addnum);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        sqlDb.close();
        return addemergnum;
    }

    @Override
    public List<AddEmergencyNumber> getAllEmergencyNumberforsms() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        List<AddEmergencyNumber> addemergnum=new ArrayList<AddEmergencyNumber>();
        sqlDb=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor=null;
        cursor=sqlDb.query(DbUtill.TABLE_ADD_EMERGENCY_NUMBER, new String[] {DbUtill.EMERGENCYNUMBER,DbUtill.SMS}, DbUtill.SMS+"=?", new String[] {"1"}, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while(!cursor.isAfterLast())
        {
            AddEmergencyNumber addnum=new AddEmergencyNumber();
            addnum.setEmergencyNumber(cursor.getString(0));
            addnum.setSms(cursor.getInt(1));
            addemergnum.add(addnum);
            cursor.moveToNext();

        }
        cursor.close();
        sqlDb.close();
        return addemergnum;

    }
    @Override
    public List<AddEmergencyNumber> getAllNumberforGps() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<AddEmergencyNumber> addemergnum=new ArrayList<AddEmergencyNumber>();
        sqlDb=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor=null;
        cursor=sqlDb.query(DbUtill.TABLE_ADD_EMERGENCY_NUMBER, new String[] {DbUtill.EMERGENCYNUMBER,DbUtill.GPS}, DbUtill.GPS+"=?", new String[] {"1"}, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while(!cursor.isAfterLast())
        {
            AddEmergencyNumber addnum=new AddEmergencyNumber();
            addnum.setEmergencyNumber(cursor.getString(0));
            addnum.setGps(cursor.getInt(1));
            addemergnum.add(addnum);
            cursor.moveToNext();

        }
        cursor.close();
        sqlDb.close();
        return addemergnum;
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteAllCallNum() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try
        {
            sqlDb=this.getWritableDatabase();
            sqlDb.delete(DbUtill.TABLE_ADD_EMERGENCY_NUMBER, DbUtill.CALL+"=?",new String[] {"1"});
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            if(sqlDb.isOpen())
            {
                sqlDb.close();
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void deleteAllSmsNum() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try
        {
            sqlDb=this.getWritableDatabase();
            sqlDb.delete(DbUtill.TABLE_ADD_EMERGENCY_NUMBER, DbUtill.SMS+"=?",new String[] {"1"});
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            if(sqlDb.isOpen())
            {
                sqlDb.close();
            }
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void deleteAllGpsNum() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try
        {
            sqlDb=this.getWritableDatabase();
            sqlDb.delete(DbUtill.TABLE_ADD_EMERGENCY_NUMBER, DbUtill.GPS+"=?",new String[] {"1"});
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            if(sqlDb.isOpen())
            {
                sqlDb.close();
            }
        }

    }

    public void deleteCallNum(String i) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try
        {
            sqlDb = this.getWritableDatabase();
            sqlDb.delete(DbUtill.TABLE_ADD_EMERGENCY_NUMBER, DbUtill.EMERGENCYNUMBER+"=?",new String[] {String.valueOf(i)});
            Log.i("DELETECALLNUMBER", "DeletionNumber");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            if(sqlDb.isOpen())
                {
                    sqlDb.close();
                }
            }
        }
    public void deleteSmsNum(String id) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try
            {
                sqlDb = this.getWritableDatabase();
                sqlDb.delete(DbUtill.TABLE_ADD_EMERGENCY_NUMBER, DbUtill.EMERGENCYNUMBER+"=?",new String[] {String.valueOf(id)});
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally{
                if(sqlDb.isOpen())
                {
                    sqlDb.close();
                }
            }
    }
        @Override
        public void deleteGpsNum(String id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try
            {
                sqlDb = this.getWritableDatabase();
                sqlDb.delete(DbUtill.TABLE_ADD_EMERGENCY_NUMBER, DbUtill.EMERGENCYNUMBER+"=?",new String[] {String.valueOf(id)});
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }



        @Override
        public void getEmergencyNumberForCalling(String id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try
            {
            sqlDb=this.getWritableDatabase();
            String query="SELECT "+DbUtill.EMERGENCYNUMBER+" FROM "+DbUtill.TABLE_ADD_EMERGENCY_NUMBER+" WHERE "+DbUtill.CALL+ "=?"+" ";
            sqlDb.rawQuery(query, null);

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {
                if(sqlDb.isOpen())
                {
                sqlDb.close();
                }
            }
            }

}
```

Comment: check that your tempPosition has the value you want in your `onClick` function.

Comment: @zozelfelfo I think so its printing object..... but I need is number... so can u suggest me ?